# multiple countdowns on same page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

i'm having a little problem with jquery/javascript countdown and i'm hoping you can help me.

so, i have timer function, which has a one parameter, called selector (jquery selector) ..

```
function timer(selector) {
    self = $(selector);     
    var sec = parseInt(self.find('span.timeout').text());

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
    sec--;
    if (sec >= 0) {
        self.find('span.timeout').text(sec);
    } else {
        setInterval(interval);
    }
    }, 1000);

}
```

in, html i have something like this.

```
<div class="element" id="el1"><span class="timeout">10</span></div>
<div class="element" id="el2"><span class="timeout">10</span></div>
```

multiple elements with same class and different id's

and the usage of the function is like this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.element', function() {
timer(this);
});
```

on the first click it works just fine, timer counts down.
but when i click on the second div with same class, first counter stops and the second goes from the previous second.

so, how can i do multiple countdowns on same page with js/jquery, so i could click on both elements and both timers work fine?

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zKTkj/

Comment: post a working example on jsfiddle so we can have a look

Comment: You really should spend some effort on your formatting, reading your question is really hard und not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You forgot to declare `self` with `var`. As a result, `self` became a global variable. You were overwriting this global ("shared") variable when the second timer was being created. So, both timers were from then on, at the same time, ouputting to the second element, causing glitches.
- You probably meant `clearInterval(interval)`.

http://jsfiddle.net/zKTkj/1/

Comment: Oh, crap.. that's the reason of working continuously and being tired.
Thank you so much : )

Comment: @Lado Lomidze: Consider adding `"use strict";` at the top of your script files, and it will throw an exception in cases such as setting an undeclared variable.